# How to compare 2 DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert `b` if element is `$("[id$=linkbuttonabsd]")` and alert `a` otherwise.

JavaScript code:

```
$("body").find("a").click(function (e) {
    var herf = $("body").find("a");
    var link = $("[id$=linkbuttonabsd]");
    var isb = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < herf.length; i++) {
        if (herf[i] == link) {
            isb = true;
        }
    }
    if (isb) {
        alert("b");
    } else {
        alert("a");
    }
});
```

But I can not achieve this by `herf[i] == link`. How should it be done?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to acheive?

Comment: Because both of them are different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.fn.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) can be used.

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and `return true` if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

```
if(herf.eq(i).is(link)){
    //Condition is ture
}
```

Also to get the element at specified index use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) rather than `[]`

You don't need to loop through the objects. *Code can be reduced to*

```
$("body a").click(function(e) {
    var herf = $("body a");
    var link = $("[id$=linkbuttonabsd]");
    var isb = herf.is(link);

    if (isb) {
        alert("b");
    } else {
        alert("a");
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.is` to match an element. Here is the example:

```
if ($(herf[i]).is("#linkbuttonabsd")) {
    isb = true;
}
```

Comment: `#linkbuttonabsd` is not the same to `"[id$=linkbuttonabsd]"`.

Comment: `[id$=linkbuttonabsd]` returns a set of elements, and that is why comparison can not be done with one element that way. I meant to solve his problem anyways.

Comment: It does work in Firefox 40 and Opera 31. If you are using very old browser (for example, IE 8-), than yes: jQuery 2.x might not work in it at all.

Comment: I thought *Version 47.0.2495.0 canary (64-bit)* is capable to run this code.